# Passing XML as a string to SOAP Request in LoadRunner

Tags: xml, soap, performance-testing, loadrunner

Anybody worked with Passing XML as a string to SOAP Request in LoadRunner?
I have around 400+ columns and 5lac rows, out of which I have to make an XML pertaining to each row, with userdefined tags. For example: 1-5 column in 1 user defined tag and 6-15 in another.

I hope I am clear.

so far:

1. Parametrization will not work, hectic task.
2. Trying to generate userdefined tags XML from Oracle db.

Pls help with the approach.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's just a sting.  Dust off your C programming skills, a foundation skill set for the use of LaodRunner with the default language for Web styled virtual users, and build the string you need dynamically.    If you want just one string to modify then for the one request impacted with the XML, make use of the web_custom_request() form of the request.   This will provide you with a single request string with all of the name value pairs as a single string (instead of as dynamic form fields) that you can modify to your heart's content.